# (Java 7) Swing application loses keyboard focus

Tags: java, input, keyboard, focus, java-7

My application is a GUI frontend for a database, and is built using Java's Swing library. The application is compiled using Java 5 (1.5).

When the application is ran using Java 7 I am able to write in textfields, comboboxes, etc. using the keyboard, until the data is loaded from the database then the cursor continues to blink but what I type is not typed on the screen. However, if I click on another windows e.g. my browser and then come back to my application, or minimize and maximize my application, the keyboard input works and behaves as normal.

When I run with Java 1.5 or 1.6, however this issue does not appear.Any insight on what might have changed in Java 1.7, and possibly a workaround?

PS: So far I made a workaround as follows:

```
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame.setFocusableWindowState(true);
```

However, I have this inside a timer, as I don't know where exactly the issue occurs. This is not really a proper solution...

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with a Java 6 application running under Java 6 and Ubuntu 14.04, however the problem seems to be a little more occasional as I was unable to detect a cause/consequence relationship so far.